# Use cases of NoLoggers

Tags: logging

I have noticed that a logger that logs nothing but only supress logs (NoLogger) actually exists. But I am not aware of its use cases (maybe except unit tests).
Do you have any experience regarding NoLoggers?

Many thanks in advance.

Understanding NoLoggers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use case is pretty simple: If you don't want any log to be created/written - that's basically it.

When do you want this? Basically, if you want to avoid any I/O-operation or to keep your server's console clear. Or simply not to log anything on the customer's system since it might expose internal stuff.

That's just to name a few examples.